# File handling in simple client-side app

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, icalendar

Need advice around options for handling a simple file download (.ics) in a Javascript app.

Assuming s.icsMsg is a well-formatted text/calendar string, the below works in Chrome:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
downloadLink.href = 'data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8,' + s.icsMsg; 
downloadLink.download = "Calendar.ics";
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink); 
downloadLink.click();
document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

File is downloaded, correctly named and opens into the mail client. In IE 9+ I get a data area size error.

Is there a way of achieving this in IE, purely on the client? I understand I can do it by setting the content-disposition in the http headers, but since the file is generate on the client-side, it's two extra hops to push it up, save it, then send it back with the correct headers (if that would even work).

Any advice would be great...

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but have you thought about the link opening an iframe with the data posted to it and having the iframe page basically just put the data posted to it into the content-disposition header?

Comment: Didn't think that was possible? Thought the headers were set on the server, and since I'm all client-side, that ain't happening. Although,  I wonder if I could do an ajax post to the same page, set the header in the post and magic something up there... Alternative is a simple service hosted on App Harbor or similar, which then creates the file on Google Drive, and returns the url which I then .click(). Maybe. Or IE could have a horrible fallback instead.

Comment: headers are set server side. But in the situation I'm thinking about is `POST`ing the data to the server. Therefore the server will have access to the data produced client-side (within the `$_POST` fields for php) and then can just take that data and put it into the headers

Comment: Only issue it can't be the server hosting the page - I don't have access (rather I do, I just want to avoid the 6-week dev-release cycle). Thinking a hosted service should do it, post to that, return with the desired headers and away we go.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Works fine in IE10/11, anything earlier I'm just not showing the link that triggers this function. Figured the majority of users will be on mobile devices, so old IE won't be an issue.

Would use window.open() for non-IE browsers, but can't find how to set the file name. Not phased though, all is working.

```
if (!s.isIE) {
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.href = 'data:text/calendar;charset=utf-8,\r\n' + escape(s.icsMsg);
    downloadLink.download = "Calendar.ics";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
else {
    var blob = new Blob([s.icsMsg]);
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'Calendar.ics');
}
```